# How to change label text with a button in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've just started learning how to develop for iOS, but have a question. I've set up a button that changes my label text when clicked, but I also want to be able to revert the label text back to it's original state after it's been clicked. My test app has a label that changes to a joke when the button below is pressed. How can I use the button to revert back to the original label text after the new text has been displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Store the original string in an instance variable. When the button is pressed, check if the label has the original string in it, if it does display a joke, if it doesn't then put back the original text.

If you want you could also have a `bool` variable `isDisplayingJoke` which you update every time the label is updated and check every time you update the label. The benefit of this is you avoid comparing strings often.